# Objective-C's #import statement - Won't Import a file inside a folder

Tags: objective-c, xcode, import

I'm new to Objective-C here, and still learning its syntax, so I'm experimenting some things... and I'm trying to understand how the #import statement works when it comes to importing a file inside a folder.

I have a main function inside of a file and in the same directory of my main function contains a folder for a class, inside that folder I am trying to import a header file for that class.

I'm trying to import it like this:

```
#import "Person/person.h"
```

And I believe that should work but instead Xcode fires off a error saying it can not find the file/directory.

The folder that contains person.h is in the same directory as my main function's file. 
I still don't understand what's wrong with that piece of code, if someone can tell me the proper way to do this it would help a lot, thanks!

Comment: try `#import "person.h"`, the folder isn't really, it is a *group*, something like a virtual folder in the project

Comment: That seems to have solve my problem, thanks!

Comment: @Vince: You should make that an answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try `#import "person.h"`, the folder isn't really. It is a *group*, something like a virtual folder in the project, that let you organize visually your project files.

Answer (score 1):

(one way) to use this functionality is to add the parent directory (of `Person/`) to your target's include paths.

Comment: If the Person directory is in the include search path, then the correct `#import` is `#import "person.h"`, as `"Person/person.h"` would search for Person/Person/person.h.

Comment: @Peter the parent directory i was referring to was the parent of `Person/` -- will clarify that.

Comment: Or add it to the "Header Search Paths" and optionally set it to recursive